# Azure budget alert schema template

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am setting up some Azure budget alerts to call a Logic App webhook to perform an action.

In the budget I have specified alert conditions to fire an action group at 25%, 50% and 75% of budget. The action group has an action to call the Logic App webhook using the common alert schema.

I have a "When a HTTP request is received" Logic App set up with the [simple alert payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-common-schema-definitions#sample-alert-payload) and a step to process the request.

In this processing step I would like to have access to details of the budget that triggered the alert (budget name, % of budget etc) but the sample schema does not contain that information:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "alertContext": {
                    "properties": {
                        "condition": {
                            "properties": {
                                "allOf": {
                                    "items": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "dimensions": {
                                                "items": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "name": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "value": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "required": [
                                                        "name",
                                                        "value"
                                                    ],
                                                    "type": "object"
                                                },
                                                "type": "array"
                                            },
                                            "metricName": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "metricNamespace": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "metricValue": {
                                                "type": "number"
                                            },
                                            "operator": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "threshold": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "timeAggregation": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": [
                                            "metricName",
                                            "metricNamespace",
                                            "operator",
                                            "threshold",
                                            "timeAggregation",
                                            "dimensions",
                                            "metricValue"
                                        ],
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "type": "array"
                                },
                                "windowSize": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "conditionType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "properties": {}
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "essentials": {
                    "properties": {
                        "alertContextVersion": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertRule": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertTargetIDs": {
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": "array"
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "essentialsVersion": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "firedDateTime": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "monitorCondition": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "monitoringService": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "originAlertId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "resolvedDateTime": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "severity": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "signalType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "schemaId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Is there somewhere that has a schema template with all of the possible fields for a budget alert? So that my Logic App can use those Budget fields as dynamic content in subsequent steps.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found the schema yet?

Comment: @Venky No I have not been able to find them yet.

Comment: I raised an issue in github- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33731#issuecomment-504524648. Hopefully they will respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a logic app which puts the input json into a blob storage. Added this Logic app as Webhook in Budget alert action group.

I received following message. This looks like the schema for budget alerts.

```
{
    "schemaId": "AIP Budget Notification",
    "data": {
        "SubscriptionName": "",
        "SubscriptionId": "",
        "EnrollmentNumber": "",
        "DepartmentName": "",
        "AccountName": "",
        "BillingAccountId": "",
        "BillingProfileId": "",
        "InvoiceSectionId": "",
        "ResourceGroup": "",
        "SpendingAmount": "",
        "BudgetStartDate": "",
        "Budget": "",
        "Unit": "",
        "BudgetCreator": "",
        "BudgetName": "",
        "BudgetType": "",
        "NotificationThresholdAmount": ""
    }
}
```

Looks like Microsoft did mention about this schema in their documentation but in a slightly hidden manner (look for the json in the below article)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-cost-management-budget-scenario#create-an-azure-logic-app-for-orchestration

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do the same thing and it looks like it is working.